# How to intercept request headers in android WebView before android-21?

Tags: android, reflection, webview

In android-21 a [new](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) callback appeared:

```
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

Any chance to have them on older API, f.e. on android-19 where [old](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) callback is available?

```
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)
```

I've tried to find invocations with headers argument ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium_org/+/android-4.4_r1/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContents.java) f.e.) but i was unable to do it though they are somewhere. Any ideas?